# Angular: How to access transformRequest data?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

In my controller I have this code to make request to my factory:

```
UploadService.news.save
                    data: angular.toJson $scope.data
                    file: $scope.file[0]
                , ( (response) ->
                    #$scope.alert = ''
                    alert response.data
                )
```

This will go to my factory:

```
app.factory "UploadService", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
    news: $resource("upload/news",
        headers:
            'Content-Type': false
        transformRequest: (data) ->
            fd = new FormData()
            fd.append 'data', data.data
            fd.append 'file', data.file
            fd
    )

    member: $resource("404/upload/member")
]
```

Problem is at `transformRequest` the data parameter is undefined, what is wrong with that? (I'm using Angular 1.2.3)

Answer (score 1):

The way you declare your resource has several errors:

1. The `$resource` second argument is an hashmap for default parameter values
2. The third parameter contains `actions` (ie methods) for this resource. If you want to override the save action, you need to give its name.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTk4M/1/) (Open your dev console, and then run)

```
app.factory "UploadService", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  news: $resource("upload/news", {}, # the missing second parameter
    save: # You want to override the save action
      method: 'POST' # it's an override, not an extend: need to set the method
      headers: 
        'Content-Type': false
      transformRequest: (data) ->
        console.log data # data is now defined
        return 
  )

  member: ...
]
```

Or see the [official doc](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/docs/api/ngResource.%24resource#example)